# How to resize multiple images

Tags: c#

My task is to resize multiple images. I tried this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Boyutlandir
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string dosyaYolu = string.Empty;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialogDosyaAc = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openFileDialogDosyaAc.Multiselect = true;
            if (openFileDialogDosyaAc.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dosyaYolu = openFileDialogDosyaAc.FileName;

                bmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialogDosyaAc.FileNames.ToString());

                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmpKucuk = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image,Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
            pictureBox1.Image = bmpKucuk;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "jpeg dosyası(*.jpg)|*.jpg|Bitmap(*.bmp)|*.bmp";
            DialogResult sonuc = sfd.ShowDialog();
            if (sonuc == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(sfd.FileName);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two down votes without a single comment :-)

Comment: Dowvoters should make at least one comment here to justify their down voting

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you have tried? Note that this question looks like "Please write my program for me" request that are not welcome by community. (I'm not a downvoter for this question yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are using winforms and want to open multiple files? or a directory? and want to resize them. but there is nothing resized? or do I need more coffee? use http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/ and I don't see a loop to loop over the files you want to resize.

Read more about the imageresizer component here: http://imageresizing.net/docs/managed

in your button1 click event, do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialogDosyaAc.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Read the files
        foreach (String file in openFileDialogDosyaAc.FileNames) 
        {
            //resize and save
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should dispose your ShowDialog() (use using)

Comment: Like Sayse said, also use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624654/which-is-a-better-way-to-call-form-showdialog